# Connection between L²-norm of function and its moment-sequence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function and define $m_i := \int_0^1 f(x)x^i dx$.

I want to somehow formalize and then show the following: If the sequence $(m_i)$ has a very small $\ell^2$-norm, then the $L^2$-norm of $f$ is also very small.

More formally, let $(M_n)$ be a sequence of moment sequences $(m_i)$ with the property that the $\ell^2$-norms of $M_n$ converge to zero. Does the corresponding sequence of real functions then converge to zero in $L^2$?

Unfortunately I do not have any idea how to approach this problem. Any reference would be helpful.

Comment: The [classical moment problem](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/akhiezer.pdf) assumes a non-negatuve function..

Comment: The normalized Legendre polynomials $\{ p_n \}$ form an orthonormal basis of $L^2[-1,1]$. Use an even extension $f_e$ of $f$ to $[-1,1]$. Then $2\|f\|^2=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}|(f_e,p_{2k})|^2$, and $(f_e,p_{2k})=2\int_{0}^{1}f(t)p_{2k}(t)dt$ can be expressed in terms of the moments $m_i$. Have you tried that?

Comment: @TrialAndError I have thought about that. But it seemed that the coefficients of the Legendre polynomial grow very quickly. Isn't that a problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is false. Let's write $f(x) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j x^j$ (one can work with polynomials and avoid the issues of convergence). Then 
$$m_i = \sum_{j} \frac{a_j}{i+j+1},\ \text{ that is, } \ m = Ha\tag{1}$$
where $H$ is the [Hilbert matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix) Also, 
$$\int_0^1 f(x)^2\,dx = \sum_{i,j} a_i a_j \int_0^1 x^{i+j}\,dx
 = \langle Ha, a\rangle \tag{2}$$ 
Hence the question becomes: is there a constant $C$, independent of $a$, such that $$\langle Ha, a\rangle  \le C  \|Ha\|^2\tag{3}$$ 
But $(3)$ is satisfied (by a positive self-adjoint operator such as $H$) if and only if $H$ is bounded from below; this is an immediate consequence of the spectral theorem. And the spectrum of $H$ is [precisely the interval $[0,\pi]$](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2372284); thus, $H$ is not bounded from below.

In particular, one can find polynomials $p$ such that the ratio $(\sum m_i^2)/\int_0^1 p^2$ is as small as one wishes.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. Since my initial guess was wrong, I was wondering what exactly can I know of $f$ from the fact that the moment sequence is small in the $\ell^2$-norm? Is there anything that I can say about $f$? Like small in $L^1$?